# The derivative of a multivariable function evaluated at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am currently looking at the problem:

> For a function $f \in C^1( \mathbb{B}, \mathbb{R}^k)$ where there exists some positive value $\beta$ such that $\lvert Df(0)h \rvert \ge \beta \lvert h \rvert $ for all $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$
>
> Now define $P: \mathbb{B} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ where $P(x) = f(x) - Df(0)x$ and calculate $DP(0)$.

I believe that the best way to find $DP(0)$ is to consider $P(x+h) - P(x)$ and look for terms that are linear in $h$ and evaluate this at $x=0$. This gives us

$$P(x+h) - P(x) = \big{(} f(x+h) - Df(0)(x+h) - f(x) + Df(0)x \big{)} = \big{(} f(x+h) - Df(0)h - f(x) \big{)}$$

Here we, see that $Df(0)h$ is linear in $h$, however, it is unclear to me whether or not $f(x+h)$ will also have linear terms and so this approach seems to be indeterminate to me.

I would be grateful for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\| P(0+h) - P(0) \| = \|f(0+h) - f(0) - Df(0)(h)\|,$$

and the derivative $Df(0)$ is the linear operator such that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if  $0 < \|h\| <\delta$, then

$$ \|f(0+h) - f(0) - Df(0)(h)\| < \epsilon\|h\|$$

Hence,

$$\|P(0+h) - P(0) - 0\| < \epsilon\|h\|$$

and the derivative $DP(0)$ is the zero operator.

In general, $DP(x) = Df(x) - Df(0)$.